# how to avoid vim breaking line beyond 80 characters in fortran files

Tags: line-breaks

I have added the following two lines into my .vimrc file

```
" stop fortran 90 from automatically insert line break beyond 80
set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0

" stop vim wrapping beyond 80, avoid visual breaking in vim
set nowrap
```

but still no success. vim keeps breaking lines in my f90 source file as before, which is very annoying. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

`'textwidth'` is local to the buffer. I imagine Vim's default fortran plugin (`$RUNTIME/ftplugin/fortran.vim`) is setting `'textwidth'`.

To override this default add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/fortran.vim`:

```
setlocal textwidth=0
```

You can set other fortran setting you wish to override here as well.

You can also use `:verbose` to see where an option was last set. e.g. `:verbose set textwidth?`.

For more help see:

```
:h 'textwidth'
:h after-directory
:h :setlocal
:h :verbose
:h :set
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are old-fashioned, you might want an alias such as

```
alias vi='vi --noplugin'
```

Then you can again rely on your own intelligence rather than vi's.

Some of the "modern" plug-ins are rather annoying if you are not used to them.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I’ve edited your post to use code-formatting, and I’ve also used a sh-style alias syntax. One thing that could improve the answer is to explain how this avoids OPs problem (the connection between the noplugin flag and ftplugins/textwidth is not immediately obvious)